# How to make webpage force to show desktop version

Tags: php, html

It's kinda silly to ask this but...

I created a webpage for my CV but the fact is it views perfectly when I browse from Computer, or I turn on *Request Desktop version* on android, so my question is if there is any way to show as desktop mode in android with or without that *Request Desktop Version* turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a variable that controls your css link to your style sheet. So you have one style sheet set up for mobile and another set up for desktop, when that button is sent to server post/request, then have the css link to style sheet page set to that CSS page.

for example:

on your php page...

```
if(isset($_POST['desktop_version'])){
    $styleSheet = "desktop.css";
    $buttonDisplay = "Switch to mobile version";
    $buttonName = "main";
}elseif(isset($_POST['main'])){
    $styleSheet = "main.css";
    $buttonDisplay = "Switch to desktop version";
    $buttonName = "desktop_version";
}else{
    // default version when neither instances have been submit yet
    $styleSheet = "main.css";
    $buttonDisplay = "Switch to desktop version";
    $buttonName = "desktop_version";
}

//... in your html head
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=$styleSheet?>">

//... in your html body your buttons value is set to the opposite of the set sheet it is using
//... when the style sheet is set to main, the button displays the attributes 
//... for the desktop version and when set to desktop it sets the attributes 
//... for the main version.
<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="<?=$buttonName?>" value="<?=$buttonDisplay?>">
</form>
```